# Django model inheritance based on atribute value it's possible?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need a class (inheritance) when the parent attribute is true, and thus when to seek the child class, bring all that hold this attribute to true. **After, I will need to use this new class in the admin panel and as foreignkey.** Eg.: CustomerServices

See the code:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    vendor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class People(Person):
    registration_number = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1)

class Company(Person):
    registration_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    foundation_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]

class Customer(Person):
    # I want to consider all Person object with customer=True

# I need this working and available in the Django Admin like others classes
class CustomerService(Customer):
    service_name...
    service_qtty...
    service_price...
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible but looks like bad design decision. What kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a separate model for that. You can can extract all customers from the Person class. i.e `Person.objects.filter(customer = True)`.
Adding the sexiness of django's ObjectManagers you can do something like.

```
class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def customers(self):
        return self.filter(customer = True)

class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = PersonManager()
```

then in your views or any other place you can call it like

`customers = Person.objects.customers()`